# SED in bash substitution with a variable, the variable being the content of another file stored in an array

Tags: bash, sed

Basically a have a "template" file I want to fill with the content of some other auxiliary files which are, basically, a matrix of numbers and letters. I make other substitutions, but this one is what's giving trouble.

In the template file I've put the "%label" at the place I want to do the substitution with the auxiliary file. Then I use this script to do the substitution:

```
for i in $(cat file_list.txt); do
    array[$i]=$(<file_$i.txt)
done

for i in $(cat file_list.txt); do
    sed -e "s/%label/${array[$i]}/g"< template.txt > final_file_$i.txt
done
```

("file_list" contains the files' names) But I keep receiving the error "sed: -e expression #3, char 58: unterminated `s' command".

I've also tried this kind of script to do that:

```
for i in $(cat file_list.txt); do
    mapfile < file_$i.txt   
    array[$i]=${MAPFILE[@]}
done

for i in $(cat file_list.txt); do
    sed -e "s/%label/${array[$i]}/g"< template.txt > final_file_$i.txt
done
```

In this case I don't receive errors warnings and the substitution is made, but without line breaks.

Is there a way of making the substitution keeping the line breaks?

Thank you.

Comment: The underlying problem is that whatever `${array[$i]}` gets expanded to by the shell is subject to `sed` syntax, which means that if your file names in `file_list.txt` are paths containing slashes (because that's what you used as delimiter in your `sed`-expression) or any other special characters from `sed`'s point of view the substitution fails.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @AdrianFrühwirth.

My filenames don't contain backslashes at the moment. Besides, when I used  "mapfile" I didn't get any errors.
I tried changing the sed separators to commas, though, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sed` requires occurrences of the separator character and occurrences of the newline character in the replacement string for `s///` to be escaped with backslashes.  The errors reported in the question are due to newlines in the files containing the replacement strings.

It's normally not a good idea to use variables in either the pattern or the replacement string for the `s///` command.

Since you are using Bash, you don't need to use `sed`, or any other external command, for this.  Try this pure Bash code:

```
template=$(< template.txt)
for id in $(< file_list.txt) ; do
    contents=$(< "file_$id.txt")
    final_contents=${template//%label/"$contents"}
    printf '%s\n' "$final_contents" > "final_file_$id.txt"
done
```